# How to translate "butterscotch pie" to Esperanto?

Tags: translation

*[Butterscotch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterscotch)* is a kind of English confectionnary and flavour. I am not sure what it is, but according to the article, it contains brown sugar, butter and other things. The French wikipédia article names it *[Caramel Écossais](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caramel_%C3%A9cossais) (Skota karamelo)* which sounds clearer, but other Wikipedia articles prefer the original English name.

About the *pie* part of the question. I am not sure if the translation should be *adjective + noun* or a *compound-noun*. The article for *Apple pie* uses *[Pomokuko](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomokuko)*.

Here is an example sentence:

> Do you prefer cinnamon pie or butterscotch pie?

Comment: And then there's the age-old question on what exactly is the difference between *kuko* and *torto*; I would say *pomtorto* for "apple pie".

Answer (score 9):

Like many terms involving food, the first question to ask before trying to translate it into the International Language is whether the concept you're translating in an international one. Do people in Germany, Russia, or Japan have a concept for what "butterscotch" is?

Benson (CEED) and Wells suggest "buterkaramelo", and I've verified that "Butterkaramell" is a valid German expression (along with "Butterbonbon" which suggests *buterbombon-gusto*). Whether these taste like butterscotch, and whether they're known in other parts of the world is another question. I'm inclined to trust Wells here.

Answer (score 5):

I would use *buterkaramelo* for 'butterscotch' (note that I would use it for 'fudge' too; you cannot expect an international language to be able to make all the distinctions that all cultures make; outside the English-speaking world people do not have concepts that precisely match up with either 'butterscotch' or 'fudge', so the fact that they get mixed up in Esperanto is not a real issue).

So "butterscotch pie" would be *buterkaramela torto* (or maybe *buterkaramela kuko*). Often the more concise *karameltorto* might be precise enough.